# What are values of fundamental frequency and the harmonics for the below signal g(t)?

Tags: signal, wave, fourier

We  know that a Fourier series formula for any signal $s(t)$ is given as

$$\frac {a_0} 2 + \sum \limits _{m=1} ^\infty (a_m \cos \frac {2 \pi m t} T + b_m \sin \frac {2 \pi m t} T)$$

Here,as we see from the formula ,except the DC component and fundamental frequency components there are all harmonics present at right side of the Fourier series formula.

Let us consider 4 sinusoidal periodic signal $$x(t),y(t),z(t) and g(t)$$ such that

$$x(t)=\cos \frac {1.2*2 \pi t} 8$$

$$y(t)=\cos \frac {1.4*2 \pi t} 8$$

$$z(t)= \cos \frac {1.6 \pi t} 8$$

and

$$g(t)=x(t)+y(t)+z(t)$$

Then,

> 1. How would you apply Fourier series formula for a signal $$g(t)$$ which is nonharmonic?
> 2. If there are fundamental frequency and harmonics present ,can anybody tell me what are they and their values?

Comment: I don't see any issue here at all. It's a composite signal g(t) comprising 3 sinewaves of different frequencies. Eventually g(t) will repeat so this limits the boundaries over the integration so what is the problem?

Comment: @Andy aka as you can in the main Fourier series formula ,there are harmonic terms present but for $g(t)$ there are no harmonic frequency components. so how Fourier series formula is valid here?

Comment: @Andy aka could you tell me  in case of g(t),what is fundamental  frequency component   here? also ,what are harmonics I.e.multiple of fundamental frequency components present here?

Comment: Model it as a harmonic sequence of cos(0.2*2*pi*t / 8) with all the harmonic weights set to 0, except for three corresponding to X,Y,Z. Job done.

Comment: @Brian Drummond I really don't get you. Why are you avoiding X,Y and Z signals ?and representing signal g(t) by sum of  other signals?

Comment: Re-read. X,Y and Z are the ones you DON'T set to zero. That means they are the only ones you're using.

Comment: @Brian Drummond OK sorry for my mistake in reading but how did you computed the term cos(0.2*2*pi*t / 8) ?

Comment: By inspection. Just look for the largest common factor.

Comment: @Brian Drummond largest common factor is 0.2,is it?

Comment: Is it a factor common to all your equations? If so, can you find a larger one?

Comment: @Brian Drummond you could not take **m** as fractional value .it must be some integer value. isn't it?

Comment: @Brian in case of 1.2,1.4 and 1.6 ,the largest common factor is 0.2 .but I don't get your sentence I.e. "If so, can you find a larger
one?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Fourier coefficients are given by the formulas:

$$a_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+T}g(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{T}\right)dx\\
b_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+T}g(x)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{T}\right)dx$$

For any integrable \$g(x)\$ on the interval \$[x_0, x_0+T]\$. For periodic functions this interval can correspond to the period of the function, such that the Fourier series will be perfectly equal to the function itself. But the case of your example is very simple - it's just a sum of three cosines, so the \$a_n\$ terms can be calculated directly and there would be three of them. \$b_n\$ would equal to zero, as there is no sine terms.

Comment: Could you tell me  in case of g(t),what is fundamental  frequency component   here? also ,what are harmonics I.e.multiple of fundamental frequency component present here?

Comment: The signal, as you can see is composed of three harmonic signals, I.e. three different frequencies. And you should be able to find them yourself. The fundamental one would be the lowest one. And there are (surprise!) two additional harmonics). As this question is suspected as a homework, I am not going to give you a complete solution.

Comment: 2.also how could you take $m$ as fractional value here?

Comment: @user3559780 if you refer to the numbers `1.2` `1.4` and `1.6` - they are not the `m`. Hint: `1.2/8 = m_1/T`, `1.4/8 = m_2/T`, `1.6/8 = m_3/T`

Comment: but how could other signals be **fractional** multiple of fundamental component with lowest frequency

Comment: I guess in your case you are using a different definition of fundamental frequency. It should be such that every harmonic is multiple of it.

Comment: you mean to say that
step 1. m_1/T=1.2/8
so step 2.m_1/T=(1.2*10)/(8*10)

I.e.m_1/T=(12)/(80) 

so m_1is equal to 12. is it?

Comment: also  should T be considered as T=80?

Comment: Actually in the equations above for `m_3` it should be `0.8/8 = m_3/T`, as there is no coefficient of `2` in the `z(t)`. So yes, the idea is to find such a smallest T which will make `m`s non-fractional. 80 is not the smallest one. The smallest one you will get if reducing the fractions. It will be 40. Sorry, gotta go. Good luck.

Comment: and whether m_1=6, m_2=7 and m_3=4? am I right ?

Comment: will you please say only "yes" or "no" regarding my previous comment.?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: thanks and sorry for tolerating so much time and concept clearance. I will go through your answer and comments again and again. if I get any doubt I will ask you

Comment: It may help if you realise that the fundamental does not have to be one of the signals in a composite waveform

Comment: @Chu could you tell more about what you want say? you mean in my question, fundamental frequency is different from those of 3 frequency components. it is not among these of 3?

Comment: @Eugene sir,I am confused again. Can you tell me what if lowest frequency m_3=4 is considered as fundamental frequency, then how other ones I.e. m_1 and m_2 are considered as harmonics of m_3? Because m_1,m_2are not multiple of m_3?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. In the formula for Fourier series,  ANY of the \$a\_m\$ or \$b\_m\$ terms can be zero. The fundamental frequency has no special privileges.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your recent comment: yes, in the formula for Fourier series, ANY of the \$a_m\$  or \$b_m\$   terms can be zero. The fundamental frequency has no special privileges.

Perhaps, to convince you, consider a composite signal:

\$g(\theta)=sin(2\theta)+sin(5\theta)\$, where \$\theta=2\pi ft=2\pi t/T\$

This does not have a component in \$sin(\theta)\$, i.e. the fundamental, yet \$g(\theta)\$ has been written as the sum of the 2nd and 5th harmonics of the fundamental. As \$\theta\$ goes from \$0\rightarrow 2\pi\$, \$sin(2\theta)\$ goes through 2 complete cycles and \$sin(5\pi)\$ goes through 5 complete cycles.

Looked at another way, \$g(\theta)\$ can be written:

\$g(\theta)=sin(\theta/0.5)+sin(\theta/0.2)\$

and the lowest common multiple of \$0.5\$ and \$0.2\$ is \$1\$